# How to load FreeDOS iso from Grub2?

Tags: grub2, freedos

I'm currently loading FreeDOS iso (freedos-1.0-full.iso) from Grub4DOS, and Grub4DOS is actually first loaded from Grub2.

**Grub2 grub.cfg**

```
menuentry "FreeDOS 1.0" {
    setroot=(hd0,1)
    linux /grub.exe --config-file="/menus/freedos.lst"
}
```

**Grub4DOS freedos.lst**

```
title FreeDOS 1.0
find --set-root /images/freedos-1.0-full.iso
map --mem /images/freedos-1.0-full.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
map --mem /isolinux/data/fdboot.img (fd0)
map --rehook
chainloader (fd0)+1
rootnoverify (fd0)
```

Does anyone know how to load FreeDOS iso **directly** from Grub2? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have [syslinux](http://www.syslinux.org) installed and copy '/usr/lib/syslinux/memdisk' to the partition also containing the grub loader (in this example '/boot/').

Add the following entry to '/boot/grub/grub.cfg':

```
menuentry 'Some FreeDOS ISO' {
        linux16 /boot/memdisk iso
        initrd16 /freedos_bootable.iso
}
```

This worked like a charm with an iso to update my ssd firmware. [More info about MEMDISK from the syslinux project](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=MEMDISK).

I am using Arch-Linux, location of 'memdisk' may differ with other distributions.